# Finding an old savings account in Minneapolis Minnesota

Tags: united-states, bank-account

I had a Franklin savings account opened in Minneapolis Minnesota over 30 years ago and I believe that I left money in it, how can I find out if I still have money?

Comment: Give them a call and ask.

Comment: If the account was closed as inactive, check the state's abandoned-property office for info about how to reclaim the funds.